# Submitting different screenshots

Tags: ios, app-store

I am submitting my app in the app store with different language. Is there a way to add different screenshots for different language or appstore? for like if I want to submit different images in france app store and different in US?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes，you can `choose another language` in Version Information  page, select that you want to add , then will get to add it.

Comment: you mean in addition to those in english I will also be able to add those that are in french? which means 8 imags for english and 8 for french?

Comment: ya, that's ok, just try it. You can upload all the images for iPad or iPhone as same as English, also descriptions.